# SpringBoot Request Mapping not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, request-mapping

I am new to spring boot and trying to make a starter application ran into this issue, the code is simple:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String allMovies(){
        return "All Movies";
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to display All Movies when i go to localhoast:8080/ but it just shows me the boilerplate no explicit mapping for error. This is a fresh project i changed nothing during the while process i just have some other classes but none of them interfere with this class. The project is here: https://github.com/hozaifaO/Movie-Review . Another note to add is that i have a similar boiler plate starter project with the same code and that one works the only difference is that this one has mongodb as a dependency. Any help is appreciated.

I was expecting a string msg but i was greeted by boilerplate error mapping page.

UPDATE: Changing the code to this did not work.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieController {
    @GetMapping()
    public String allMovies(){
        return "All Movies";
    }
}
```

However, i did try to do this in a different class so i made the mapping happen in the Application class and it works if i do it in that class but i dont want to. Here is the code from that class,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public class MovieReviewApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieReviewApplication.class, args);

    }
    @GetMapping
    public String root(){
        return "Movies";
    }
}
```

All the code can be seen on the Github page link above including the pom file.
Video of me running the software and showing whats wrong https://www.veed.io/view/3b14100c-c541-4d0d-9ffd-477439c3747e?panel=share

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: Use `@GetMapping` instead of RequestMapping, or else, specify the type of REST Request i.e. RequestMethod.POST or RequestMethod.GET if you want to use `@RequestMapping` annotation ! If the issue still persist, do post, your POM.xml file ! Also, since the browser initiates a request which is by default GET in nature, but it may not be a good programming practice

Comment: @Harsh `method=RequestMethod.GET` is the default. But yes `@GetMapping` would be better.

Comment: @Harsh I tried that and that did not work the updated code file and the pom file are all on github repo linked in the question.

Comment: What are you using the `spring-dotenv` dependency for? Try removing it.

Comment: @ValerijDobler I tried that and it still doesnt work i created a new class and made is it controller and no other class is controller and the mapping still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RequestMapping is both a a class level & method level annotation.
At class level ,it is used to create base URI.
Every URI specified in method level annotation is appended to base URI
specified on the top of the class.The URI specified at method level is added to clearly define or identify that the specific method of the class has been made request to.
In addition you can use ,path parameters, method=get/post/put etc attributes in method level annotation. The new way of implementing method level annotation is @GetMapping/@PostMapping.

You need to specify baseURI @ class level & Can use @Getmapping or @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) at method level.

Missing class level annotation is causing the issue.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MovieController {
   
    @GetMapping
    public String allMovies(){
        return "All Movies";
    }
}
```

Comment: I rearranged and did what you said but i still get the white error page with /error mapping information. The updated code is on the github repo linked in the question above.

Comment: I updated the question maybe it gives enough clues for you guys to help me.

Answer (score 1):

put this

@RequestMapping("/")
on top of the class and rename it to movies
this method can look like this

```
@GetMapping
public String allMovies(){
    return "All Movies";
}
```

Comment: I rearranged and did what you said but i still get the white error page with /error mapping information. The updated code is on the github repo linked in the question above.

Comment: i updated the question perhaps it gives enough insight for you to help me

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You need to mention movies in url like this "http://localhost:8080/movies". You are accessing "http://localhost:8080/". Since your url is incomplete ,you are getting default error page

[image]

Comment: Nope i do add the /movies every time i recorded the code running on my machine to show the issue. https://www.veed.io/view/3b14100c-c541-4d0d-9ffd-477439c3747e?panel=share I think i might just delete it from the pc and pull it from github again.

Comment: Even making a new project by pulling the current one from github and running doesnt fix the issue.

Comment: Your main application class is not a Rest Controller .  Remove @RequestMapping("/test") & root method from there. If you need that code ,create separate TestController class ,just Like MoviesController. Clean & Rebuild the code. It will work

Comment: Yah i understand the main class is not Controller i was just trying to see if its working when i do it in that class vs the controller class i wrote

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the second class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public class MovieReviewApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieReviewApplication.class, args);

    }
    @GetMapping
    public String root(){
        return "Movies";
    }
}
```

into two different classes, first one is for running spring boot application with @SpringBootApplication annotation, BUT without any mapping methods,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MovieReviewApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieReviewApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

and second new one only with mapping

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String oneOfMyControllerMethod(){
        return "Movies";
    }
}
```

and test it locally

Comment: Yes i only put that in the main to test if the issue was only happening outside of the main class and that seems to be the case. If you look at the bottom of the question i have a video running the project and tryin to acess the url's and it doesnt work giving me an error. At this point i am so confused honestly.

Comment: Check the github and you can try removing the mongodb dependency and running it to see if its a machine issue because i am starting to think it is

Answer (score 0):

I ended up Just restarting with a new project and choosing the same dependencies and it seems to work. Not too sure what exactly was causing the issue but it i suspect it was not a programming issue.

Comment: It's good that you share how you solved the problem. However, in this case it might have been better to update your question (add a section with this text), or to write it as a simple comment to your question.